# Swift Code Sign Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on a project in Swift, and when I try running the project on my actual device, I get the error:

```
/Users/alexyuiop/Desktop/Pitch²/build/Debug-iphoneos/PitchSquared.app: the main executable or Info.plist must be a regular file (no symlinks, etc.)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I've looked at some other posts with the Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 error, but those solutions don't seem to work for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Would the special character (²) possibly cause this problem?

Comment: have you used provisioning profile in xcode .. It's error for not valid provisioning profile

Comment: yeah, I selected a valid provisioning profile in xcode

Answer (score 0):

Have select here developer profiles for debug .. In this image not saved any profile .. so you need to developer profile only for debug in device .. May be help full for you...

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to choose development or distribution profile

Comment: What did you create provisioning profile on https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action here..

Comment: Yeah I went there and created an App ID and used that to generate a new Provisioning profile

Comment: Then go to Target setting and there option for Team below of Version &  Build . Add there your apple account. may be help full..

Comment: Yeah I did that before. I don't think it has anything to do with my selected provisioning profile because I've recreated it more than 3 times